# oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ incompatible with oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I am fetching a value from oracle database using eclipseLink as ORM. There is a column in my table with data type ***TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE***
For that column I am getting

> java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ incompatible with
>   oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ

*When I opened class org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.Oracle9Platform::getTIMESTAMPTZFromResultSet() method is converting this data type.*

I just want to know where I am wrong or Am I missing some config?

**OJDBC dependency**

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>oracle</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
      <version>11.2.0.3</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
```

---

**Oracle Version**

```
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
```

---

**Eclipse Link Version**

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
   <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
   <version>2.7.2</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

---

**Server Liberty**

---

**Exception**

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ incompatible with
>   oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:58)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.getSingleResult(EJBQueryImpl.java:402)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ
>   incompatible with oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.Oracle9Platform.getTIMESTAMPTZFromResultSet(Oracle9Platform.java:238)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.Oracle9Platform.getObjectFromResultSet(Oracle9Platform.java:205)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.getObject(Data
>   aseAccessor.java:1305) at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.fetchRow(DatabaseAccessor.java:1080)

---

**EclipseLink Method**

```
/**
     * INTERNAL:
     * Get a TIMESTAMPTZ value from a result set.
     */
    public Object getTIMESTAMPTZFromResultSet(ResultSet resultSet, int columnNumber, int type, AbstractSession session) throws java.sql.SQLException {
        TIMESTAMPTZ tsTZ = (TIMESTAMPTZ)resultSet.getObject(columnNumber);
        //Need to call timestampValue once here with the connection to avoid null point
        //exception later when timestampValue is called in converObject()
        if ((tsTZ != null) && (tsTZ.getLength() != 0)) {
            Connection connection = getConnection(session, resultSet.getStatement().getConnection());
            //Bug#4364359  Add a wrapper to overcome TIMESTAMPTZ not serializable as of jdbc 9.2.0.5 and 10.1.0.2.
            //It has been fixed in the next version for both streams
            Timestamp timestampToWrap = tsTZ.timestampValue(connection);
            TimeZone timezoneToWrap = TIMESTAMPHelper.extractTimeZone(tsTZ.toBytes());
            return new TIMESTAMPTZWrapper(timestampToWrap, timezoneToWrap, this.isTimestampInGmt);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: This is a class loader issue. The class loader used to load the EclipseLink and its comparison (TIMESTAMPTZ) class is not the same as the one used by the application, making it so that TIMESTAMPTZ =! TIMESTAMPTZ. I've hit this issue when the driver and JPA classes were in multiple class loader levels. I don't know your server setup, but you should focus on Server Liberty and how it is loading the persistence units and drivers.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the reply, though I saw it late, yes the problem was same. Actually Same class was loaded by different classloaders.